# Vuejs: How to go to a page after authenticating with Firebase

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

New to vue.

I have a vue 2 + router setup. All seems to be working fine. Now I want to got to the first page of my site after authenticating with Firebase. I authenticate, email is verified, would like to do it the "vue way" to enter the site.

I'm kind of stuck here. With the error: push is not defined. Was assuming that would take me to the correct component.

```
Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {

    if (firebaseUser) {

        if (firebaseUser.emailVerified == true) {

            // alert("User is verified");

            // ERROR HERE, NEED TO NOW ENTER SITE. LEGIT USER
            this.$router.push({ path : '/home'});

        } else {
            document.getElementById('btnLogout').style.display = 'none';
        }

        firebaseUser.sendEmailVerification().then(function() {
            console.log('Send verification email');
        }, function(error) {
            console.log('Error: Did not send verification email');
        });

    } else {
        console.log('Not loggend in');
        document.getElementById('btnLogout').style.display = 'none';
    }
})
```

Comment: Where is this code? In a Vue lifecycle handler? Could you also show where/how the router is defined if not.

Comment: `console.log(this)` first. it sounds like it's not a Vue instance.

Comment: Put your `onAuthStateChanged` method in a Vue `mounted()` method

Comment: hi daniel, Ok, that worked, thanks.

Comment: bret, kira thanks. i just had to bring the firebase code into the mix. It was hanging out on it's own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [Myfirebase](https://github.com/myfirebase/myfirebase) it is a decoupled SPA framework which is highly compatible with Firebase and its easy to use.

In this use case, the authentication module is already built in the framework, and it could be triggered globally though components.

Example:

- We are going to determine if the user is signed-in or not.
- We are going to retrieve the user email through Firebase auth.

App.vue :

```
<template>
   <div class = "container">
      <h1>Welcome {{useremail}}</h1>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
    mounted() {
      this.$auth.state({
         forward: "/app", // the user is signed-in
         redirect': "/login", // the user is not signed-in, redirecting to login
         then: (user) => {
            console.log(user.email)
            // retrieve useremail
            this.usereamil = user.email
         },
         catch: (error) => {
            console.log(error.message)
         }
       })
    },
    data() {
      return {
         useremail: ""
      } 
    }
 }
</script>
```

This project still in development stage.
if you have any question, feel free to submit any issue or pull request.

Comment: Thanks, feel free to submit any issue or pull request